# Silverlight cannot see my Webservice class whereas my Winform project can in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, silverlight

I have created a basic asmx webservice helloworld. In Winform I have added it as Webreference

and called it like this (Hello being a class inside the Webservice of course):

```
MyWebserviceReference.Hello hello = MyWebserviceReference.Hello();
```

Visual Studio 2010 accepts it.

If I do the same thing with Silverlight in the same solution referencing the same webservice, it does recognize MyWebserviceReference but not the Hello Class it says am I missing a reference to an Assembly. Why in Silverlight and not in Winform ? How to fix this ?

Is there something more to do in Silverlight than in Winform than just adding a reference to the webservice ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **service reference option instead of the webrefrence option** on your silverlight project, then check for refrence.cs in your silveright project folder to see if the correct proxy class is genarated

Comment: I used the service reference in silverlight since there is webreference option :).

Comment: In service references project folder there is the proxy service as namespace. There's never a reference directly to a class as far as I know.

Comment: is 'hello' a input param or return type of one of your methods if so, there should be a class with that name in your proxy.

Comment: of course Hello is a class. The very problem is that he cannot see it in silverlight whereas it can in winform. So is there something more to do in Silverlight than in Winform than just adding a reference to the webservice ?

Comment: Well syntax not the same at all http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Consuming-ASMX-Web-Services-with-Silverlight-2.aspx